# How to deploy a simple Spring Boot (with Gradle build system) to Apache Tomcat (real server, not embed server)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I follow this tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ 
This is my project structure:
[image]

**`build.gradle`**

```
buildscript{
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar{
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies{
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") 
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

**`Application.java`**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**`Greeting.java`**

```
package hello;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

}
```

**`GreetingControler.java`**

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }

}
```

I know how to run Spring Boot application by **`gradle bootRun`** command (run on Apache Tomcat embed server). But I don't know how to run above Spring Boot application on real Apache Tomcat (Please help me at this point!)

[image]

Comment: See the [official Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-traditional-deployment).

Comment: I try so hard, but can not create war file for deploy or run/debug on real Tomcat server. Please help me an explicit answer.

Comment: Try to add `apply plugin: 'war'` and then print  `gradle war` in console. BTW, in Idea it's really handy gradle menu, so you would not even need to print something in cmd

Comment: @Enigo, I also change `apply plugin: 'jar'` to `apply plugin: 'war'`, then use command `gradle war`, but not success.

Comment: @manish, I also read official Spring Boot document, then apply, but my application not done. If you **really have answer and you have construction spirit** for the problem, you should post your own answer clarify.

Comment: @dovy, I didn't mean to offend but from your comments it seems that I did; my apologies.  I did want to help; however, packaging a Spring Boot app for a container deployment is a considerably long task, steps for which are already covered in the documentation, which is why I pointed you to the section which describes the whole process.  I would suggest starting with an auto-generated Boot project, following the documentation to generate a WAR, deploying it on Tomcat and making sure that everything works.  Then start adding your custom code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @dovy, you may also want to look at using the [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io) to generate a new Spring Boot project with WAR packaging.  Make sure to switch to the full version using the link at the bottom of the project page.  Once you have confirmed that the WAR works with your Tomcat installation, you can add your custom code to the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow [comments's manish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702975/how-to-deploy-a-simple-spring-boot-with-gradle-build-system-to-apache-tomcat#comment59104877_35702975), I create source base from http://start.spring.io/

[image]

Then I import to Eclipse for Java EE (with Spring Tools Suite, Gradle plugin), this is project folder structure:
[image]

**`Greeting.java`**

```
package hello;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

**`GreetingController`**

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

I modified file **`GsRestServiceApplication.java`**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GsRestServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreetingController.class, args); // <-- modify this line.
    }
}
```

I don't change file **`GsRestServiceApplication.java`**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(GsRestServiceApplication.class);
    }

}
```

I can run web app in real Tomcat server:
[image]

Then I use browser or Postman to view result:

```
http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service/greeting?name=Vy
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're using Gradle. Try to add this in your build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
   providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```

Don't forget to remove:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
```

Comment: The application will not work if remove `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")`

Comment: Removing `spring-boot-starter-web` helped in my case!