# Why is the main method not called when run spring boot project with external tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I made deployable war following this article.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

then, run with external tomcat.

why is the main method not called when run with external tomcat? (but process works well)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I run with java -jar xxx.war, this main method has been called well.

is there anything I missing?

Comment: Do you have `@SpringBootApplication` in the class?

Comment: Yes, i declared.

Comment: do you use maven? can you show pom.xml?

Comment: project(deployable war) is work well with external tomcat. but main method is not called. is this related to maven?

Comment: If you deploy using maven

Comment: I use gradle also deploy this to tomcat manually and run ./startup.sh

Comment: so check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702975/how-to-deploy-a-simple-spring-boot-with-gradle-build-system-to-apache-tomcat

Answer (score 1):

When a spring boot application is deployed to an existing tomcat container, the application is initialized by the ServletInitializer, so it will only run the configure method in the Application.class